# How to access elements from different packages?

Tags: java, eclipse, oop

I want to access **Element1** of **com.A** in **com.B**. I have created object of class **Event1** in **com.B** and called method **EventNames** using the object but no luck.

Following is the sample code.

```
//package com.A
public class Event1 {
   public static void EventNames()
   {
       ArrayList<String>List = new ArrayList<String>();
       List.add("Deposit");
       String Element1 = list.get(0);
   }
}
```

```
//package com.B;        
import com.A.*;
public class Event2{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Event1 ev = new Event1();
        ev.EventNames();
        
        system.out.println(Element1); //this line throws error
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your actual code into your question, don't retype it. And give the full text of the erro rmessage/stack trace of an exception.

Comment: But anyway. The scope of `Element1` is restrcited to the body of `EventNames()`. Maybe you should make `EventNames()` return a value? And please use Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

`EventNames` is a `static` method, which means that it belongs to the `class` rather than the object(s) instantiated from that class. So, you could call it like `Event1.EventNames()`, yet, this does not solve your problem yet, because `Element1` is only a local variable, computed in your method and the method does not return anything. So, let's modify your method to return your string list:

```
//package com.A
public class Event1 {
   public static ArrayList<String> EventNames()
   {
       ArrayList<String>List = new ArrayList<String>();
       List.add("Deposit");
       return List;
   }
}
```

Notice that I do not return a single `String`, because the name `EventNames` suggests that we have a collection of events whose names we are interested about when calling the method. Now, let's get the list and print the first element:

```
//package com.B;        
import com.A.*;
public class Event2{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        system.out.println(Event1.EventNames().get(0));
            
    }
}
```